# How to remove all links from a string that does not have an absolute link?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that contains text and some links. I want to remove all the links that do not have absolute links but keep their text.

I want to do it with regex instead of loading the dom.

Is that possible?

I have tried this regex

```
preg_replace('#href=["\']([^/][^\':"]*)["\']#', $root_path.'$1', $html);
```

But this will replace the href with an empty string only.

And I want to completely remove the anchor tags and keep its text only.

Comment: So, for example, if the HTML was `Hello <a href="https://www.example.com">world!</a>` the output should be `Hello world!`?

Comment: No, The href is absolute in this case, so it should stay as it is. If the href is a relative URL then yes it should remove the link from the world!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex, but take it with a pinch of salt! It's far from perfect, so try it for your use case and if anything goes wrong, just write in the comment and I'll try to fix the regex for you!

```php
<?php

$re = '/<a(\s+[\w-]+?(=([\'"].*?[\'"])|([\w\d]+?))?)*\s+href=[\'"](?!https?:\/\/)(?<link>[^\'"]+?)[\'"](\s+[\w-]+?(=([\'"].*?[\'"])|([\w\d]+?))?)*>(?<text>.+?)<\/a>/m';
$str = '<a class="aaa" href="/example" data-enabled>Hello</a> <a href="https://www.example.com">world!</a>';

$string = '<a href="/example">Hello</a> <a href="https://www.example.com">world!</a>';

$out = preg_replace_callback($re,
 function($matches) {
    return $matches['text'];
 }, $string);
 
var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regex

```
$text = "Lorem <a href='#'>text</a>
Lorem2 <a href='#'>text2</a>";
$text = preg_replace_callback('/<a .*>(.*)<\/a>/mi', function($matches) {
    return $matches[1];
}, $text);

var_dump($text);
```

Output will be like that

```
string(24) "Lorem text
Lorem2 text2"
```

Run in sandbox:

https://onlinephp.io/c/3bda8